# Python3: SQlite3 list format

Tags: python, sqlite

when i fetch data from a table in SQlite3 it formats each value       ('value',)
the data in the column:
Regi
Bob
Jeff

how to i remove/ stop the extra round brackets and comma?

```
c.execute('SELECT Name from information')
data = c.fetchall()
valNameNS = data
valName = str(data)
valNameL = list(valNameNS)
print(valNameL)
[('Regi',), ('Bob',), ('Jeff',)]
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't even tell what you're asking.

Comment: how do i remove the round brackets and extra comma

Answer (score 2):

The items in parenthesis with commas are length-one tuples. Use a list comprehension to extract them.

```
new_list = [x[0] for x in valNameL]
```

Comment: Beat me to it. But `valNameL` is not needed in the first place. You can get rid of those lines (cast to string, using `list()`) and just use `data`.